# Is there a toggle switch that returns to default state on power off?

Tags: switches, toggle-switch

In my car there is a switch to control traction control that's Normally Closed that I want to swap to Normally Open, however there is a problem. When the car is turned off and back on, the state resets to closed. I want to replace the switch but I also want to keep this feature.

Is there a momentary button operation switch that will toggle signal wire open/closed but will default to NO when power is lost?

Comment: Any electronically controlled button will do that (or a button latched by an electromagnet when pressed but I don't know if those exist).

Comment: you can wire the button to a relay that self-triggers to "latch" open until power is removed. Or use a triac instead of a relay, and trigger with the button.

Comment: @dandavis Note that if using a triac you may not be able to "unpress" the button without powering it down without additional measures (which would also be required to unpress electromagnetically latched button). It's one thing to make something volatile that just latches when pressed and stays that way until powered down. It is another thing to make it so you can also unlatch it while powered.

Comment: @DKNguyen: true, same for a self-latching relay. OP didn't mention "canceling" it, so I assumed it was ok. If that feature is needed, I don't see a way to avoid a 2nd button, unless we go to a simple MCU or clever multi-discrete solution; OP can look for a "soft latch circuit".

Comment: @dandavis I initially assumed it was okay too but then upon reading the question again, I think he may want the option to turn off traction control without shutting the car down.

Comment: Should be able to do this with a mom-off-mom DPDT switch, a relay (possibly DPDT), and some cleverness.  Momentary on to latch the relay, then momentary off (or power down the car) to unlatch the relay.

Comment: Unless the switch just tells the car's computer to do the traction control thing.

Comment: @TimWescott Good point. What happens if you hold the switch *while* the car starts up?

Comment: Your assuming the switch does anything other than momentary connection to a ECU or BCM. It's notthe switch that is latching it's the car computer. Get the service manual and check the wiring guide. Or see if it's a dealer chargeable feature.

Comment: A circuit with a J-K flip flop could do it. But it's already an electronic device.

Answer (score 3):

Since I do not have reputation to comment, I am posting my answer here:

Look at [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/499168/little-circuit-to-turn-off-startstop-of-my-car/499244#499244), where OP wants to do something similar with start&stop system. You can use the same circuit i drew in the answer.